# unable to read opensslv.h:No such file or directory

Tags: macos, error-handling, terminal, openssl, installation

I am getting the following error when I try to install [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) version [1.0.1h](http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1h.tar.gz) on MAC OS (Mountain Lion) Terminal,

> unable to read opensslv.h:No such file or directory

I am using the following command in the Terminal,

```
sudo /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared
```

I am following the instructions on [this link](http://foodpicky.com/?p=99). What is wrong here?

Comment: The link `http://foodpicky.com/?p=99` is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am following the instructions on this link. What is wrong here?

You did not follow the instructions. It looks like you missed step 06:

```
06. cd into openssl-1.0.0c as follow...
```

---

> sudo /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared

Don't `make` with `sudo`. Try this:

```
/tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared
make -f /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Makefile
sudo make -f /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Makefile install
```

Its usually easier if you `cd` into `/tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/` first. Then it reduces to:

```
tar xzf openssl-1.0.1h.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1h
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared
make
sudo make install
```

---

You could also use the following to avoid memorizing the triplet:

```
export KERNEL_BITS=64
./config shared no-threads shared no-ssl2 ...
```

---

After make install, OpenSSL will be installed in `/usr/local/ssl` unless you change it with `--openssldir` or `––prefix`.

---

> sudo /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared

`––prefix=/usr` is probably going to be a pain point for you. Apple ships with OpenSSL 0.9.8, which is *not* binary compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.1h. You should experience unexplained crashes and unexplained incorrect results once you replace the system's version of OpenSSL with your version.

---

Finally, before you `sudo make install`, you should `make test` to ensure everything is OK.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Hope you can help with similar one here in this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591690/how-to-run-multiple-lines-of-commands-in-terminal-from-applescript

Comment: Hello again "jww". I am getting an error when trying to install OpenSSL. See this link please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664151/target-already-defined-darwin64-x86-64-cc-offending-arg-prefix-usr