# How to run multiple lines of commands in Terminal from AppleScript?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, applescript

Please refer to this question first,

[unable to read opensslv.h:No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559703/unable-to-read-opensslv-hno-such-file-or-directory)

Based on that I need to run the following three line Terminal commands using AppleScript,

```
/tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared
make -f /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Makefile
sudo make -f /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Makefile install
```

I tried two methods I created text files with ***.command*** and ***.sh*** extensions and added the above three lines. Then tried to run it from AppleScript as,

```
do shell script "/Users/Username/Desktop/RunScript.sh"
```

But got this error,

```
error "/Users/Username/Desktop/RunScript.sh: line 1: /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure: No such file or directory
/Users/Muhriz/Desktop/InstallOpenSSL.sh: line 2: make: command not found sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" number 1
```

This could work,

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate
tell application "Terminal"
    do script ("/tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc ––prefix=/usr no-threads shared") in window 1
    do script ("make -f /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Makefile") in window 1
    do script ("sudo make -f /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h/Makefile install") in window 1
end tell
```

But it asks for password in Terminal at the third line and waits for user response. The password dialog shown from the AppleScript (when using `with administrator privileges`) is OK. But it must no ask for password via Terminal when running the commands. It needs to ask only once when the AppleScript is executed and run all `sudo` related commands without asking for password in Terminal.

What code needs to be used to run from AppleScript?

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following before running your scripts.

```
chmod a+x /Users/Username/Desktop/RunScript.sh
xattr -r -d "com.apple.quarantine" /tmp/ssl/openssl-1.0.1h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do shell script "/Users/Username/Desktop/RunScript.sh"
```

That doesn’t work because you can’t pass a path to the “do shell script” command, you can only pass it the contents of the actual script.

If you want to run a bash script that is contained in its own file, you can use TextEdit to open the bash script file and set the contents of the file to a variable, which you can then pass to “do shell script.”

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    set theDesktopPath to the path to the desktop folder as text
    set theShellScriptPath to theDesktopPath & "RunScript.sh"
    open file theShellScriptPath
    set theShellScript to the text of document 1
    set theScriptResult to do shell script theShellScript
    make new document
    set the text of document 1 to theScriptResult
end tell
```